# active directory monitoring

Tags: .net, active-directory, network-programming, system-monitoring, zabbix

I want to develop a monitoring tool to monitor active directory like (solar wind,op manager etc).
For this purpose,I have chosen Zabbix(an open source tool) to monitor AD and provide me real time values so that i can plot those results on my Front-end.
To monitor any process/service by zabbix, i need to provide its complete path to zabbix.
i have monitored some services like lsass.exe,ntfrs.exe and get their successful results.
but i am facing a problem in monitoring ntds.dit.
can any one tell me how to monitor ntds.dit?as this is in binary format so unreadable.

Secondly,Windows Performance Monitor provides all the parameters that i need for monitoring.but i dont know how to read that values from WPM.

can any one help me in getting values from WPM or is there any service that can give me ntds info(ldap,ab client session etc..) so that i can plot it on my front end.

Answer (score 0):

Ntds.dit is an [Extensible Storage Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Storage_Engine) database. It contains all the Active Directory LDAP objects. It is opened exclusively by LSASS while the system is running with ADS enabled. The only time it wouldn't be locked is when the system is in ADS recovery mode or when the file is in something like a VSS snapshot.

All the relevant data in the ntds database can be accessed through LDAP; you shouldn't need to touch the database file directly.